# Extend kartik GridView widget class - Advanced application yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, extend, kartik-v

I want to create a new class that extend from yii2 Kartik gridview

```
namespace mywidget\grid;

use kartik\base\Config;
use kartik\dialog\Dialog;
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\bootstrap\ButtonDropdown;
use yii\grid\Column;
use kartik\grid\GridView as YiiGridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
class GridView extends YiiGridView
{

}
```

the problem is when i call grid view , an error exception is thrown : Class not found.
So i wonder if it'is the right way to extend from a widget class ??

Comment: Is this exception about missing `kartik\grid\GridView` class? Or other?

Comment: no,the exception is about my class which is not found  : use mywidget\grid\GridView;

Comment: check namespace and path

Answer (score 1):

The namespace you have used is not registered.

The simpliest solution is to change the namespace to one of the registered with Yii 2.

- for Basic Project it's `app` - so if you the path to your extended class is `mywidget/grid/GridView.php` namespace is `app\mywidget\grid`
- for Advanced Project it's `common`, `frontend` or `backend` so depending on the one you choose place folder there and replace `app` accordingly

If you insist on using `mywidget\grid` namespace you have to register it first. Read more about this in the Guide: [Class Autoloading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html)

Comment: i change it to common\widgets and i put the namespace : namespace common\widgets;
and after this i put : use common\widgets\grid\GridView in my view file.
But same error

Comment: You have set different namespace than you call. It's `namespace common\widgets;` and then `use common\widgets\GridView;` **OR** `namespace common\widgets\grid;` and then `use common\widgets\grid\GridView;` (class must be in one additional folder `grid` as well).

Answer (score 0):

> the exception is about my class which is not found : `use mywidget\grid\GridView`

it sounds like it's an autoloading issue, make sure the file you're working in has the same path in your project as the namespace you're using. in this case should be `mywidget\grid\GridView.php` or adjust your namespace to match your file location

.. if that's not the case please provide more details about the error you're receiving and use case of your class